# Android send header request to Laravel

Tags: android, laravel, header

This is my android code

```
    @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
            headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
            headers.put("access_token", "4b1fhb4fhbjkhgdekfjhwkefhiu4iuiufhf");
            return headers;
        }
```

And Laravel to get access_token

```
    public function talk(Request $req)
    {
    $access_token = $req->header('access_token');
    .............
```

But $access_token return NULL. Please give me your thought!
Or give me another way to solve.
Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

try to change

> use Illuminate\Http\Request;

into

> use Request;

Comment: Why would you need to use something already in the namespace? Also that line is not mentioned in the question. Lastly that would not cause the parameter to be null.